# JavaScript: register a custom script type and define a handler?

Tags: javascript, dom

HTML  elements with a unique custom *type* attribute are ignored by the browser. Sometimes these are used by template engines. How do I define what happens when such a script element is loaded/created? (either while loading the page or when inserted dynamically)
In other words, does an onCreateElement event of some sorts exist in the DOM?

I could quite easily iterate through all script elements with attribute *type=text/mycustomtype* when the DOM loads using for instance the *querySelector* and then parse them with a function. This however does not work when a new script element is created and appended programatically. Is this currently possible?

```
var d = document.createElement('script')
d.setAttribute('type', 'text/mycustomtype')
d.innerHTML = 'define foo = 1;' // some code in some custom language
document.body.appendChild(d)
```

In this case, nothing will happen because the browser will ignore this unknown type. Can I somehow define a handler function for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Why do you need to add these elements after the DOM loaded? If the DOM and scripts have a lready been loaded, why wouldn't you just call the handler directly? `myHandler('define foo = 1;')` ?

Comment: I think my question is pretty straightforward. I want to define a new script type that will be interpreted by a custom function the moment it is initialized.

Comment: I understand. I don't that's possible so I'm suggesting alternatives.

Comment: If you'd really like to do this for whatever reason and detect changes in the document, have a look at Mutation Observers.

Comment: @yezzz I already did. However I could not make it work by observing the document element. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I have little experience with it. You could edit your question or create a new one with the observer code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw python script running in a browser [using brython](http://brython.info/console.html).  View source and I see:

```
<script type="text/python3">
  from interpreter import Interpreter

  # open REPL in textarea with id "code"
  Interpreter("code")
</script>
```

I wanted to know how this is possible.  I googled for the answer, and found the dreaded stackoverflow question that's exactly what I want - with no answers.

I found a good answer in: [Everything I Know About The Script Tag](https://eager.io/blog/everything-I-know-about-the-script-tag/).  It's exactly as you predicted when you say *iterate through all script elements*.

Their example looks like this:

```
<script type="text/emerald">
  make a social network
    but for cats
</script>

<script>
  var codez = document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/emerald"]');
  for (var i=0; i < codez.length; i++)
    runEmeraldCode(codez[i].innerHTML);
</script>
```